# regular expression match methods with python

Tags: python, python-re, regular-language

There is a string text

```
<R-PORT-PROTOTYPE>
  <SHORT-NAME>VtDBGO_ReMotTqReqL2_null</SHORT-NAME>
  <REQUIRED-COM-SPECS>
    <NONQUEUED-RECEIVER-COM-SPEC>
      <DATA-ELEMENT-REF DEST="VARIABLE-DATA-PROTOTYPE">/FS_DBGO_pkg/FS_DBGO_if/VtDBGO_ReMotTqReqL2_null/VtDBGO_ReMotTqReqL2_null</DATA-ELEMENT-REF>
      <USES-END-TO-END-PROTECTION>false</USES-END-TO-END-PROTECTION>
      <ALIVE-TIMEOUT>0</ALIVE-TIMEOUT>
      <ENABLE-UPDATE>false</ENABLE-UPDATE>
      <FILTER>
        <DATA-FILTER-TYPE>ALWAYS</DATA-FILTER-TYPE>
      </FILTER>
      <HANDLE-NEVER-RECEIVED>false</HANDLE-NEVER-RECEIVED>
      <INIT-VALUE>
        <NUMERICAL-VALUE-SPECIFICATION>
          <VALUE>0</VALUE>
        </NUMERICAL-VALUE-SPECIFICATION>
      </INIT-VALUE>
    </NONQUEUED-RECEIVER-COM-SPEC>
  </REQUIRED-COM-SPECS>
  <REQUIRED-INTERFACE-TREF DEST="SENDER-RECEIVER-INTERFACE">/FS_DBGO_pkg/FS_DBGO_if/VtDBGO_ReMotTqReqL2_null</REQUIRED-INTERFACE-TREF>
</R-PORT-PROTOTYPE>
```

How can I replace the SHORT-NAME of `VtDBGO_FrMotTqReqL2_null` with the attribute  content.
just like  the following string text

```
<R-PORT-PROTOTYPE UUID="E8000CF6-DAFD-49C7-B1D4-D7EC20F43654">
<SHORT-NAME>VtDBGO_FrMotTqReqL2_null</SHORT-NAME>
<REQUIRED-COM-SPECS>
  <NONQUEUED-RECEIVER-COM-SPEC>
      <DATA-FILTER-TYPE>ALWAYS</DATA-FILTER-TYPE>
    </FILTER>
    <HANDLE-NEVER-RECEIVED>false</HANDLE-NEVER-RECEIVED>
    <INIT-VALUE>
      <RECORD-VALUE-SPECIFICATION>
        <FIELDS>
          <NUMERICAL-VALUE-SPECIFICATION>
            <SHORT-LABEL>ElementConstant</SHORT-LABEL>
            <VALUE>0</VALUE>
          </NUMERICAL-VALUE-SPECIFICATION>
          <NUMERICAL-VALUE-SPECIFICATION>
            <SHORT-LABEL>ElementConstant_1</SHORT-LABEL>
            <VALUE>0</VALUE>
          </NUMERICAL-VALUE-SPECIFICATION>
        </FIELDS>
      </RECORD-VALUE-SPECIFICATION>
    </INIT-VALUE>
  </NONQUEUED-RECEIVER-COM-SPEC>
</REQUIRED-COM-SPECS>
```

Here is my two solutions ,but it didn't work

```
pattern_update=re.compile(r"""<R-PORT -PROTOTYPE>
\s+<SHORT-NAME>{0}</SHORT-NAME>
.*?<INIT-VALUE>((?:.(?!<REQUIRED-COM-SPECS>))*?)</INIT-VALUE>.*?
\s+</R-PORT-PROTOTYPE>""".format(port),re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
            _ar_xml_str = re.sub(pattern_update, replace_str, ar_xml_str)
            ar_xml_str = _ar_xml_str
```

```
        pattern_update=re.compile(r"""<SHORT-NAME>VtDBGO_ReMotTqReqL2_null</SHORT-NAME>
.*?<INIT-VALUE>(.*?)</INIT-VALUE>""",re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
        _ar_xml_str = re.sub(pattern_update, replace_str, ar_xml_str)
        ar_xml_str = _ar_xml_str
```

Comment: Don't use regular expressions for XML. Use an XML parser instead.

Comment: Thx, let me have a try.